# Responsive gallery alignment issue(Bootstrap-gallery & justifyGallery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [jquery-justifyGallery](https://github.com/iekadou/jquery-justifyGallery/) and [bootstrap-gallery](https://github.com/iekadou/bootstrap-gallery/) for displaying all the images for the gallery. I would like to display 4 images in a row. When the number of images is multiple of 4, it is not a problem. However, if I would like to display 5 images, the image of 5 which is located at last row will have bigger width. I understand that bootstrap has 12 columns in each row. Anyone here have any idea on solving this kind of problem?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <h3 class="gallery-title">The Rainbow Run - 07 Dec 2014</h3>
        <div class="gallery row">
            <a href="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/1.jpg') }}" class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/1.jpg') }}">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/2.jpg') }}" class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/2.jpg') }}">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/3.jpg') }}" class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/3.jpg') }}">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/4.jpg') }}" class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/4.jpg') }}">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/5.jpg') }}" class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/gallery/rainbow_run/5.jpg') }}">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('.gallery').bootstrapGallery({});
$('.gallery').justifyGallery({
    'maxRowHeight': '400px',
    'spacing': 10,
    'resizeCSS': {
        'min-width' : 0,
        'width': '300px',
        'max-width' : '300px'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  div.col-sm-7.seven-three{width:60%!important;}
  div.col-sm-5.five-two{width:40%!important;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 seven-three">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#000;">Column 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#333;">Column 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#444;">Column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#555;">Column 4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#666;">Column 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3xuybnje/

Comment: Can you explain more? I understand that your code is to display five images in a row. But I want to display just 4 images in a row and 5th image will move to second row if there have 5 images to display. The 5th image should be same width with the previous image instead of have bigger width than the previous one.

Comment: See my created example five images in one row working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/3xuybnje/